# get the middle folder of a file from a path in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file under "modules/test/main/main.js" and i want to get the "test" folder :

I tried this code but all i get is the `main` folder

```
path.basename(path.dirname('modules/test/main/main.js'))
```

Comment: I think this should include the `node.js` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on `/` and than drop off last item as it is file name.
and than take the middle element

```js
let path = `modules/test/main/main.js`

let middle = path.split(/\//g)
middle.pop()
console.log(middle[Math.floor(middle.length-1)/2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) to go up two directories, and then get the [`basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) of the directory:

```
const p = 'modules/test/main/main.js';
const dir = path.basename(path.join(p, '../..')); // 'test'
```